# MassTransit RuntimeServices RabbitMQ - Integrate it with NuGet MassTransit Installation?

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, nuget, masstransit, saga

I have a ASP.NET project that utilizes MassTransit and RabbitMQ for a messaging bus, and I'm trying to implement MassTransit Sagas and I want to use the ScheduleTimeout abilities of a Saga, which requires MassTransit.RuntimeServices (TimeoutService).

However, as I'm come to learn, NuGet installations of MassTransit do NOT include RuntimeServices, which seems stupid to me, but oh well.

So I tried to pull out MassTransit.RuntimeServices and MassTransit.RuntimeServices.Database and include it directly in my project, which lead to a number of errors, including references that wouldn't resolve or restore and the pervasive use of msmq instead of rabbitmq in RuntimeServices.

After I hacked it together to stop the reference errors and tried to replace msmq with rabbitmq references, the app throws exceptions at runtime and then totally breaks my application, requiring unloading the RuntimeServices project and restarting the server.

Does anyone have any idea on how to integrate RuntimeServices into a NuGet installed version of MassTransit, which uses Rabbit MQ instead of MSMQ?

Thank you

Comment: There's [this article](http://macdonaldsmith.typepad.com/my-blog/2013/03/masstransit-getting-the-timeout-service-to-work-with-rabbitmq.html), which might help

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you can't use the Timeout Service with RabbitMQ. It's not a huge amount of work to get working but it won't be trivial. It will mean marrying some glue between the assumptions around how MSMQ works and how RabbitMQ actually works.

Comment: Okay thanks - The only part that I really need from RuntimeServices is  the TimeoutService and I already have my own worker configured with RabbitMQ, so could it be possible to splice up the project, pull out all of TimeoutService stuff (including the Saga stuff) and integrate that specifically into my project, including the persistence of Timeouts?

Comment: Yeah, you can totally do that. The Runtime Services service doesn't contain much but configuration, so most of the code in MassTransit assembly and you could implement within your own services.